# Mapper using multi-threading?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, automapper

Is there a `Mapper` that maps one list to another using multi-threading?

```
var mappedItems = Mapper.Map<List<ItemDto>, ObservableCollection<Item>>(dtos);
```

Obviously, under the hood `Mapper` is processing `ItemDto` to `Item` one by one. This operation is literally asking "Please! do me multi-threaded!". But I can't find the option. I'm looking for something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
});
```

I couldn't find anything that would help me :/

Comment: No - don't do this. Just map on a single thread. It is a waste of resources to parallel this.... is this wpf/winforms or aspnet?

Comment: Why would you need such a mapper? How many objects are you trying to map? Unless you want to map several thousands of objects at once, the parallelization overhead will be greater than any speedup

Comment: @CallumLinington I have 16 cores. Why would I use just one ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's 200k items, it takes 5-7min to map.

Comment: How are you going to *display* 200K items on the client? What are you trying to do?

Comment: BTW, when you have 200K items, you don't have an automapping problem. You have a bulk export problem. Most likely, you shouldn't use a mapper at all. Parallel LINQ can process an convert a lot of data in parallel. `Select` after all is a mapping operation. You could get *better* performance though if you could export the data to wherever you need on the server, in its final form

Comment: I missed the part where you had 200k items and it takes 5-7min - like Panagiotis says - the why here probably needs explaining because mapping 200K items just sounds extreme

Comment: Why not use a hybrid approach, e.g. map-reduce, using a mapper from some partitioning level down, where the thread/task orchestration overhead is not so noticeable (e.g. below 5%) and joining/aggregating/reducing the results in a container?  Perhaps do this for each big collection.  Some objects might contain such collections and other *satellite* fields/properties, so you could still use a mapper for those, creating exceptions/filters for the mentioned collections you'll handle manually.  Dataflow in TPL might help **a lot** here.

Comment: @CallumLinington I have 200k items in my table. I need to display them in WPF app in the datagrid. Before displaying them I need to convert a few columns. I'm doing my own custom lazy-loading in background thread, so the user doesn't have to wait to see first results. I also need fast search/filter - that's why I thought, having everything in memory (it's like 300MB, not bad) would be a good idea. And it will be FAST, when it's finally loaded.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you suggests creating a View in database? I was thinking about that, but the conversion/mapping is quite complex (and it involves regexes), so I wasn't sure

Comment: Okay - still no. No one ever could digest 200k items. only like 10-20 at a time if that. Just query the table, (I guess SQL) is far more optimised for this than you give credit for (or could do yourself just by putting it in memory). Databases weren't created because you could easily store everything in memory...

Comment: @LouisaBickley *don't* load all the data. Users aren't going to view them. They will view only one screenful at a time. That's why controls support *data virtualization*, virtual scrolling and paging. These techniques allow the control to request only the data it can display (and the next screenful). With paging, the user clicks on the previous, next buttons to request a new page. With virtual scrolling, the control raises an event when it needs more data.

Comment: @LouisaBickly both techniques require to modify your EF/LINQ or SQL query to support paging. With LINQ, loading the next page uses the `.Skip((pageNum-1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize)`. In SQL, you can use the `OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT` keywords [as shown here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)

Comment: Guys, but with paging, when someone wants to search for some text (that's result of conversion/mapping), I will have to query the items, do the mapping every time. It could be slow.. but it's worth of trying

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using Repository/UoW pattern and EF. I guess, I could change it to paging very easily by creating "GetRange" method in my ItemRepository. More work will on UI/DataGrid side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already been said in comments, you probably should redesign your database logic to be able to query data page-by-page, with some filters on either server or client side.

However, if you still need a transform/convert some data, want to do this in background, with ability to parallelize the code, you can try out the [`TransformBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782.aspx) from [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx), like this:

```
public class ItemDto { }
public class Item { }

var transform = new TransformBlock<ItemDto, Item>(dto => new Item(),
    // all cores can be used for processing
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount });

var dtoList = new List<ItemDto>();
foreach (var item in dtoList)
{
    transform.Post(item);
}
```

As you can see, block is convertible to [`IObservable<ItemDto>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160306.aspx), and can be easily used with UI:

```
IObservable<Item> observable =  transform.AsObservable();
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to avoid touching database, so I could try changing DAL. I will also try `TransformBlock`, looks interesting. Will let you know how it went